# how to implement time based authentication on google doc/spreadsheet with the help of php

Tags: php, google-docs

I have only one confusion and want to share with the help of scenario.

Suppose, I have a scenario like below:

I have one `test@gmail.com` account and one document namely `vivtest.docx,`

Now,

1. How I can provide privileges to test account for access the `vivtest.docx` file on `08 & 09 November` in write mode between `3:00-4:00 PM`
2. Access the same file on `10th Nov` in read mode between `6:00-7:00 PM` and rest of the days in November can comments.

Can you give me any sample php code to implement the above scenario?

Comment: ...on Google Documents? On Google's website? Does Google offer any such feature...?

Answer (score 0):

You will use the Drive API to alter the permissions at the appropriate times. See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions